# Links in justified items

Tags: html, css, tablelayout

I have some justified list items. I want to go to appropriate links inside list items when clicking in these list elements.

http://codepen.io/asimkt/pen/ZYqaax

My html:

```
<ul>
  <li class="btn"><a href="#">2</a></li>
  <li class="btn"><a href="#">3</a></li>
  <li class="btn"><a href="#">4</a></li>
  <li class="btn"><a href="#">5</a></li>
  <li class="btn"><a href="#">6</a></li>
</ul>
```

My css:

```
ul {
  list-style:none;
  width: 400px;
  background:#aaa;
  border-collapse: separate;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
li {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
  width: 1%;
  padding:5px;
}
li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
li:hover {
  background:#eee;
}
li > a:hover {
  color:#3cfc2c;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

As you can see I can go to links by directly clicking over them, but i want to go to these links when clicking on the list items.

I can do that by providing some padding, but the number of list items is unknown so the width of each list item also is unknown. So I can't give some fixed padding.

How can I set the anchor tag occupying all spaces inside its parent list element?

Comment: Since i got the answer, I am posting the link of what was i need. http://codepen.io/asimkt/pen/OPBOKm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this selector:

```
li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

to

```
li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 15px;
  display: block;
}
```

And the entire area should be clickable.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about it.